# Get Json passed through Http request

Tags: php, json, http

I am building an API in PHP and when a user uses the api to POST or PUT, they will pass some data through in JSON format. When the request arrives at the script intended, what php function do I use to get access to the data sent?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see that but it's exactly what I'm after. Should i delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

there is json_decode function that takes string input converts to json array or object... [here](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.json-decode.php) you can read documentation.

Comment: How do I get access to the actual json itself though?

Comment: $json = json_decode($_POST['json_string');
print_r($json);

Comment: @tanaydin — That would only work if, after the data was JSON encoded, it was also `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded or `multipart/form-data` encoded. That's sometimes done for POST requests, but is really uncommon for PUT requests.